# PyQt progress bar with QProgressDialog unable to reset

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I have a simple progress bar that I want to pop up inside loops, like in the example below.

I have to instantiate it outside of the app, then adjust values for the loop. Why? I would've thought it'd be more ideal to instantiate a new progress bar class inside the MainWindow, but that doesn't show up. I assume it has to do with the `app.exec`. However, if I add a `self.exec` for the progress bar, it doesn't update, so what's the correct way of implementing it?

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setText("CLICK ME")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.testloop)


    def testloop(self):
        n = 200
        print(progressbar.wasCanceled())
        progressbar.setMinimum(0)
        progressbar.setValue(0)
        progressbar.setMaximum(n)
        progressbar.show()

        for i in range(n):
            progressbar.setValue(i)
            if progressbar.wasCanceled(): # How can I un-cancel and reset the progress bar again?
                break


class ProgressBar(QProgressDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setValue(0)
        self.setModal(True)

    def step(self, i):
        self.setValue(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(mainwindow)
    mainwindow.show()

    progressbar = ProgressBar() # Do I need to instantiate a progressbar here,
                                # or can I instantiate and kill it inside the app code?

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: In your case the for loop is very short 200 takes a moment so you can not see the progress. what is your question?

Comment: I can very clearly see the progress though, given what I assume is the GUI needing some extra time to draw the updated value.

Comment: You have calculated how much time it takes to perform the for? Is it more than 30ms? I think not so you can not see the progress. Remember that the minimum refresh time of a normal screen is 30 ms. I think that this iteration takes less than 1ms so even if you try to refurbish it will not do so given the short time.

Comment: Okay, so I found the problem. The above thing works for some weird reason when instantiated and then shown/hidden, whereas a newly instantiated progress bar only chooses to display above a certain limit, as QProgressDialog has a `minimumDuration()`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple implementation of progress bar for a loop:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys
import time

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setText("CLICK ME")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.testloop)


    def testloop(self):
        n = 10

        progressbar = ProgressBar(n, title = "Copying files...")

        for i in range(n):
            time.sleep(0.01)
            progressbar.setValue(i)
            if progressbar.wasCanceled():
                break


class ProgressBar(QProgressDialog):
    def __init__(self, max, title):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumDuration(0) # Sets how long the loop should last before progress bar is shown (in miliseconds)
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setModal(True)

        self.setValue(0)
        self.setMinimum(0)
        self.setMaximum(max)

        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(mainwindow)
    mainwindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```